# AWS cloudtrail with S3 data events enabled create logging loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

I've created AWS cloud trail and pointed it to S3 bucket with data event configuration to log all S3 data events:

```
eventSelector: [
      {
        readWriteType: 'All',
        includeManagementEvents: true,
        dataResource: [
          {
            type: 'AWS::S3::Object',
            values: ['arn:aws:s3'],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
```

Not surprising, this created logs loop - cloud trail write to S3 logs, which generates new trail, resulting in writing to S3 and so on. My question here is about best practices: What should I configure? I don't want to exclude the logging bucket from the logs, so I am thinking to exclude only cloud trail write events that are done by cloud trail. Looking for better ideas...